# How do you know why the AI is sour at you?

Tags: warlock-master-arcane

I was playing as *Lich King V* and encountered the following enemy Warlocks:

- Ash-Haar the Wisest
- Rjakh
- Miralibus the Hat

While Miralibus stayed friendly with me most of the time and issued only one small (100) gold request, Rjakh immediatly declared War by demanding all of my Gold which I was unable to fullfill obviously. Also Ash-Haar was declaring War pretty fast on me and both disliked my by "90" (actualy value in the game) without me killing something from them or entering their Territory.

**So how is determined if an AI declares War or dislikes you? Is it predetermined by race?**

Comment: Just what we need, racist AIs.

Comment: It seems in the original release version of the game the AI is very aggressive, with war being almost unavoidable - some reviews on the net mentions this problem/feature. Maybe it will change in future patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By opening the diplomacy screen and mousing over the portrait of an AI Great Mage, you can get a numerical value of their attitude towards you, along with a list of the factors that sum up to this attitude.

For example, "Envy of the Leader" is -15 attitude, and current war is -100 attitude. "Religion" is a factor somehow, but I'm seeing a positive value for that vis a vis a Great Mage with perfect indifference towards every god.

I'm not sure how the demand system works, but my guess is AI will issue demands if their attitude is negative.